# Межфайловое взаимодействие в C++!

Tags: c++

Интересует вопрос по межфайловому взаимодействию в C++.

Есть два файла *main.cpp* и *some.cpp*, где *some.cpp* подключается в *main.cpp*

Если содержание файлов следующее:

*some.cpp*

```
int var;
```

*main.cpp*

```
extern int var;
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> int var уже определена в some.obj

Хотя я же ее вроде как не определяю повторно, а объявляю.

И второй вопрос: Есть ли смысл использовать extern если подключаемый файл имеет расширение .h?

То есть если теперь будет *some.h* и *main.cpp*

*some.h*

```
int var;
```

*main.cpp*

```
var = 4; // Так тоже будет работать
```

Так есть ли смысл писать в *main.cpp* `extern int var`?

Comment: some.cpp подключается в main.cpp - то есть #include "some.cpp"?

Comment: some.cpp подключается в main.cpp? Просто никогда так не делайте.

Comment: Да. На сколько я понимаю, так делать нельзя?)
То есть сборщик сам объединяет эти файлы?
Тогда если не писать этой строки(c include), то зачем вообще extern, если и без него работает?

Comment: Сделайте file.cpp и в нем пропишите #include some.h, снова будут сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Нет, если подключать some.h, то никаких ошибок нет

Comment: Вот это странно, поскольку ситуация с определением в разных файлах одной переменной повторяется... Посмотрим что гуру скажут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значит так, пройдёмся по азам.

В языке C и производном от него C++ бывают предварительные объявления (декларации) и определения (дефиниции). Декларация означает «вот такая штука где-то есть», а определение — «вот такая штука есть, и вот она». Например:

```
extern int var; // предварительное объявление: переменная int var где-то есть
int var;        // определение: переменная int var -- вот

// то же для функций
void f(int x); // предварительное объявление: функция f где-то есть

void f(int x)  // определение: вот она, функция f
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Предварительные объявления могут встречаться сколько угодно раз, а определения — только один раз. Это важно.

Теперь, предварительные объявления обычно кладутся в header, который можно включать где угодно. Это ничему не мешает, если в нём есть лишь предварительные объявления.

Определения кладутся в cpp-файл, который не включается никем. Тем самым при компиляции этого cpp-файла компилятор видит много предварительных объявлений и одно определение.

---

Что пошло не так у вас? А вот что. Когда вы включили один cpp-файл в другой, то у вас как бы содержимое одного файла включилось в другой. В результате переменная `int var`, с точки зрения компилятора, получилась определена дважды — один раз в main.cpp, и один раз — в some.cpp. Когда вы пишете `#include`, компилятору всё равно, что в каком файле лежит: он просто тупо подставляет содержимое подключаемого файла вместо `#include`, и считает, что оно тут и было.

---

Таким образом, как нужно делать? А вот как:

```
// в some.h
extern int var; // объявили переменную для тех, кто будет подключать header
```

```
// в some.cpp
int var;        // а вот сама переменная
```

```
// в main.cpp
#include "some.h" // подключили объявление...
// ...
var = 4;          // ... и теперь можем использовать
```

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо!
А что касается второго вопроса? Если все итак работает без extern, зачем его писать?

Comment: @Antoshka004: По поводу второго вопроса: если вы напишете `int var;` в header'е, то все, кто подключает header, будут видеть определение! А значит, если много файлов подключает header, переменная будет определена много раз — а так нельзя.

Comment: Вроде все понятно, но остался вот такой вот вопрос:
Почему если и main.cpp и some.cpp содержат определение переменной var, то не возникает никаких ошибок?

то есть в main.cpp есть код int var; и в some.cpp он тоже есть, но все работает и если в main.cpp вывести переменную вар на экран. То он выведет то содержимое, которое присваивалось в main.cpp

Comment: @Antoshka004: Не совсем понимаю — а каком случае не возникает ошибок? Если у вас в двух cpp-файлах определена переменная, должна быть ошибка от линковщика.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в первом случае возникла потому, что у вас действительно объект с именем `var` определяется два раза, при условии, что файл с именем `some.cpp` включается с помощью директивы `#include` в файл с именем `main.cpp`, как, например,

**some.cpp**

```
int var;
//...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "some.cpp"
extern int var;
//...
```

В этом случае вы имеете две единицы компиляции `some.cpp` и `main.cpp`, которые компилируются раздельно, и в каждой из которых имеется определение

```
int var;
```

Например, в `main.cpp` после включения в него `some.cpp` единица сомпиляции будет выглядеть следующим образом

**main.cpp**

```
// #include "some.cpp"
int var;
//...
extern int var;
//...
```

Поэтому линковщик вам сообщает об ошибке, так как переменная `var` определена два раза в двух единицах компиляции.

Вам следует создать заголовочный файл и туда поместить объявление переменной `var` если эта переменная должна использоваться в нескольких единицах компиляции.

Например,

**some.h**

```
extern int var;
```

И эта переменная должна быть определена только в одной единице трансляции, например, в `some.cpp`, который не должен включаться в `main.cpp`ю Например,

**some.cpp**

```
#include "some.h"

int var;
//...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "some.h"

//...

int  main()
{
    var = 4;
    //...
```

Обратите также внимание на то, что вы не должны инициализировать переменную `var` при ее объявлении со спецификатором `extern`, как, например,

```
extern int var = 4;
```

Иначе это объявление снова превратится в определение переменной `var`, и у вас возникает такая же ошибка, как была раньше в вашем исходном примере.

Answer (score 1):

some.cpp подключается в main.cpp, то есть просиходит буквальная подстановка текста some.cpp в файл main.cpp перед компиляцией. В итоге и в main.cpp и в some.cpp появляется строка int var; что закономерно приводит к сообщению об ошибке.

Comment: Так в main.cpp же extern int var

Comment: А препроцессору все равно: ему сказали #include - он и вставляет весь файл целиком. В итоге в some.cpp определение переменной и в main.cpp определение все той же переменной. Два определения - ошибка

Comment: Да, да, понял.
То есть исполняемые файлы компоновщик собирает сам?
Подключать нужно только заголовочные?

Comment: Скорее не сам, а по списку из системы сборки типа make. Обычно через #include заголовки подключают, да.